# How to truncate after [[:space:]] && '(' in BASH scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, truncate

Thanks for your help guys;
the cut command only truncates [breaks lines into fields] after single character searches so it's not as useful as sed in some cases
Here 
cut -d ' ' -f1 // the -d ' ' uses the space as place to split the line into fields are denoted by -f# using -d '-' spilt man -k . into usable f1 and f2 with | like so I'm not sure what &| the 2?> stuff means other than it passes the return values to next function somehow. I dunno why this is useful yet.
man -k . &| cut -d '-' -f2 should get the descriptions of the commands

while grep -o seems useful
grep -v seems broken
the tr and split command seems useless as I can seem to pipe data to/from that command

I have been trying to Truncate line input after space and I am not really getting the results I want. I have tried split sec `cat` `tr` commands and I am not able to parse data files yet. Using `man bash` and there I discovered the sys variable `IFS=""` I set it as so from the default. I don't see any positive results from this in `bash -i` interactive mode. After setting IFS I get ambiguous redirect errors when piping using '>'.

Basically trying this command:

```
man -k [:alnum:] > $HOME/Documents/fcList.txt && shuf -n 1 $HOME/Documents/fcList.txt
```

I want to parse the `fcList.txt` to prefix the first word up to `[[:space:]]` with either a line number or man. That way I can view a random man page entry and learn something. Even in the mousepad text editor I cannot find and replace strings that start with `"[[:space:]](*"` or `" ("` to end of a line.

I've searched around and tried IRC #BASH no help thus far. This seems promising

```
IFS=: read -ra arr < <(grep "^$USER:" /etc/passwd)
for a in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "[$a]"; done
```

however, doing this my elements are broken up like so:

```
[Text] 
[] 
[Levenshtein (3pm) - calculate the Levenshtein edit distance between two...]
```

I Basically want to extract the Levenshtein part and run it as "man Levenshtein" to finish my ranman script.

This command doesn't work -m 1 means look for 1st match

```
cat $HOME/Documents/out.txt | grep -m 1 ^.[[\(]*.[[:alnum:]]?.[\)].*[[:space:]].*[[:alnum:]]]
```

Should the `?`, `^`, `*`, `#` chars go after the `.` (is this concatenation?)
from what I'm understanding the `^` is NOT and `*` means multiple letters whereas `?` means once matched -- `c[ao]t` is both `cat` and `cot`.

also tried the parenthesis don't help my send the out.txt to grep command

```
cat $HOME/Documents/out.txt | ( grep -m 1 .^[[\(].*[[:alnum:]].?[\)]*.[[:space:]]*.[[:alnum:]]] )
```

There's a command called accessdb which tries to parse var/cache/man/index.db it may have other commands to manpage the wc is higher than apropos . or man -k ''

Thanks ALL -- But While my goal has been accomplished by your helpful answers I still do not know how to truncate properly using sed or grep.  I guess that . is not concatenation in Linux. I might have learned enough with cut to make a dat file with fields like ? a b c d ... ~correctAnswer I want to learn the [0 ... MAX] formatting I think I can make a multiple choice questioner dat file. Perhaps later try to matchup command to description.

Lastly I want to work on ZeVeRoH which is like linear algebra mixed with Sudoku everything adds to zero and you have to select +/- in matrices.

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to improve the formatting?

Comment: I have tried to clean up a bit your post, but sadly your post is really confusing and not clear. Could you try to atomize your problem and write down a clear problem statement? _(1) This is what I want (2) This is where I am stuck (3) This is what I tried (4) This is the input I have (5) This is the output I get (6) This is the output I want._ [mcve]

Comment: I edited it. Yes its confusing but so is the man bash verbosity that was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

To show a random `man` page you can use

```
man "$(man -k . | cut -d' ' -f1 | shuf -n1)"
```

On some BSD systems you can use `shuffle -p2 -f-` instead of `shuf -n1`.

As a shortcut, you can add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias rdman='man "$(man -k . | cut -d" " -f1 | shuf -n1)"'
```

Comment: The `*` in `man -k *` will get file glob expanded?

Comment: And it doesn't work on my system, cause `*` get's expanded and substituted for all the files in current dir, and man just displays usage page. However `man -k ''` runs fine.

Comment: Thank you for your hints! Found the reason why I thought that `man -k *` worked. In my home directory, there are folders like `Documents`. These are also keywords that appear in a lot of man pages. So `man -k *` in my home directory is `man -k Documents Downloads ...` which matches a lot of man pages.

Comment: It worked on my ubuntu system but I wasnt able to symlink or ln it because the spaces get parsed as variables for the command Perhaps Messing with the IFS variable will help? But for me its worse with just "<space>"

Comment: @Punkroku what do you want to symlink? If you want a shortcut for that command, define it as an alias in your `.bashrc`: `alias randman='man "$(man -k . | cut -d\  -f1 | shuf -n1)"'`. By the way, Kamil Cuk wrote `''` (two single quotes without a space), not `" "` (quoted space).

Comment: @Socowi I always confuse alias with ln link and symlink thanks. PS the way its written the perhaps the out needs " and inner '    but as a executable script file that alias command works!

Comment: cut: the delimiter must be a single character

Comment: @Punkroku That's because Stackoverflow removed duplicated spaces. Please make sure that there are two spaces after `\ `: `cut -d\<space><space>`.

Comment: alias rdman="$(man -k [:alnum:] | shuf -n 1 | sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*//;s/^/man /')"

Comment: the cut command works well does it use spilt command?

Answer (score 2):

To get a random man page try

```
man -k [:alnum:] | shuf -n 1 | sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*//;s/^/man /'
```

Direct execution is done via

```
$(man -k [:alnum:] | shuf -n 1 | sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*//;s/^/man /')
```

or

```
man $(man -k [:alnum:] | shuf -n 1 | sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*//')
```

To change your file try

```
sed -i -e 's/[[:space:]].*//;s/^/man /' $HOME/Documents/fcList.txt
```

And just prepend each line

```
sed -i -e 's/^/man /' $HOME/Documents/fcList.txt
```

And put a line number in front

```
awk '/^/ {print i" "$0;i++}' $HOME/Documents/fcList.txt
```

And `gawk`since version `4.1` can do it inline

```
gawk -i inplace '/^/ {print i" "$0;i++}' $HOME/Documents/fcList.txt
```

Comment: Thats great but it doesnt execute the command man it treats it as printf data. Can you explaing the .* part is this concantenate any number of slashes? the ; then ends the command should there be && at that point

Comment: @punkroku Then just `$(man -k [:alnum:] | shuf  -n 1 | sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*//;s/^/man /')`

Comment: A good start for you is `man sed` and [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)

Comment: sed actually seems a bit of an overkill for this one to me. `man "$(man -k [:alnum:] | shuf -n1 | cut -f1 -d' ')"` should do.

Comment: im looking at man sed and I dont understand the -e script option it is very underwritten is it its own scripting language or POSIX or REGEXP?

Comment: is it possible with tr all these commands and I still dont understand how to use them. Thus the need for the ranman script =/

Comment: sed `-e` just _adds_ another sed script to run. `sed 'script to run'` or `sed -e 'script to run'` are the same. For the `-i` sed option you need to add `-e` explicitly  or specify the optional filename for `-i`. Sed has it's own script language, with own (pattern and hold space) quirks.

Comment: `man -k .` or `man -k ''` is the way. On my system `man -k [:alnum:] | wc -l` -> 1457 lines , `man -k . | wc -l` -> 23955 lines.

Comment: what is the /^/ the up carrot is  like ! in C code right?? ('d' != 'D') or is it for the /// expansion of parse line as stated in man bash

Comment: http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html is a pretty good introduction to sed scripting

Comment: No. stackoverflow is not a learning site. Grap [this site](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), it's just great. If you wish to learn about regex, [regex crosswords](https://regexcrossword.com/) will get you there in seconds. The `^` simbolises beginning of the line. The `///` is not an expansions, but `s` is sed command for substitute, and `s/<regex>/<regex>/` is the most common used command in sed scripts.

Comment: That regex crossword cool but I got stuck on #2 .*M?O.*

Comment: @Sam that sed.html is awesome I wish I could lookup a library of useful htmls like zipSites or TorrentDNS with like a voxel based web browser like minecraft WEB for simple sites like g0-s.top/chess

Comment: https://regexcrossword.com/challenges/beginner/puzzles/4

Comment: I had a similar confusion with the MOD REWRITE in .htaccess file when rewriting URLS.

Comment: `sed` parses script. `sed -e 'd'` runs sed with a script `d` that deletes everything. Teh `s/^/man /` substituted the beginning of the line with `man `, so basically it adds `man ` at the beginning of the line, prefixes the line, yes. The substitute command has syntax as indicated in manual page `s<some char><regex><same char><regex><same char>` so you can `s#^#man #` or `s!^!man !` or `s/^/man /` all work the same. The `.*` matches eny character zero or more times. Insert regex on [this site](https://regexr.com/) if you don't understand it.

Comment: The `s/[[:space:]].*//` matches a single character that is indicated by the `[:space:]` set, can be newline space or tab, than matches any number of characters after it and substitutes it for nothing, thus removing it from the line. The `d` removes whole line not part of it. Read the documentation.

Comment: http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html has some good stuff (I learned a few things) but be aware that it has some misinformation, too. Sometimes it corrects itself later, but a lot of folk won't read the whole thing through. Take it with a grain of salt. Definitely check other sources and compare - that will net you a ton of value.